# JSON - Ruby objects key naming

Tags: javascript, naming, ruby, json

Ruby object has method/property:

```
def tentakles_count
  8
end
```

JavaScript object has key/property:

```
{ justEnough: true }
```

Now, when JavaScript gets serialised ruby object via XHR or WebSocket, developer has to use alien naming convention to access `tentacles_count`.

The same goes for Ruby, when it gets json object POSTed, developer has to use alien naming convention to access `justEnough`.

What would you do to deal with this little imperfection without going too crazy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ruby and its commonly used libraries and gems tend to blur the lines between `method/property` and `key/property` using `attr_accessor`, essentially giving an object both a property and getter/setter methods in one line. Either explicitly or implicitly, you'd have

```
def tentacles_count
  @tentacles_count
end

def tentacles_count=(n)
  @tentacles_count = n
end

def to_json
  # loop over all instance variables and convert them to json key-value pairs
end
```

(variables beginning with `@` have object scope instead of method scope).

If it's not possible to do exactly this (say `tentacles_count` needs to dynamically count tentacles while you're in Ruby), to_json can be defined so as to include public methods as keys and their return values as values.

On the flip side, a json object parses most naturally into a Ruby Hash object (a dictionary). The syntax for accessing hashes is different from method notation (`obj['justEnough']`), but there are several library gems that will let you use the familiar convention if you really want to. I think the best pattern is to use the hash as an argument to an initializer: for example, [OpenStruct](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/ostruct/rdoc/OpenStruct.html).

Obviously there is no fully general answer to this question: there is, and of rights ought to be, awkwardness at the interface between different high-level languages. You can look at these little imperfections as a reminder to avoid tight coupling or duplicated logic between the different systems.